# reStructuredText: Add credit line to an image

Tags: image, restructuredtext, credits

I have recently started a new blog, and I'm using Wikimedia images in it. I would naturally like to properly give image credits.

[image]

The conventional credit location is below the image (here, for example, in gray font).

My blog is written in [Pelican](http://blog.getpelican.com/) and i use [reStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html) to write my posts, so an image is inserted in the following way:

```
.. image:: images/Steve_Jobs_and_Bill_Gates.jpg
   :target: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Steve_Jobs_and_Bill_Gates_(522695099).jpg
   :alt: Joi Ito from Inbamura, Japan, licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution 2.0 Generic license
```

**Does reStructuredText have a credit field which will appear below the image?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you're still wondering this, since this post is a year old.

However, I am using the "Better Figures and Images" python plugin by Duncan Lock (see http://duncanlock.net/blog/2013/05/29/better-figures-images-plugin-for-pelican/) to have captions below my images. I bet you can use that for credits, also.

Comment: Hey again, Adam! First question: do you know how to use pelican plugins? That will help me know what you need to know. :)

Answer (score 0):

The standard reStructurdText ["figure" directive](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#figure) may be your friend:

```
.. figure:: example.jpg
   :alt: image of a blue triange

   Blue triangle by Dr. Beispiel.
```

For rendering examples see, e.g., https://docutils.sourceforge.io/test/functional/expected/standalone_rst_html5.html#images-and-figures